# Is there a way to find whether authentication followed MSA or Azure AD in MSAL.js

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I tried using the code provided here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2

It works for both MSA and Azure AD authentication. I need to know whether the email address entered was MSA or Azure AD. Is there a way to find that out from the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the id_token you get back, there's a `iss` (issuer) claim.
This claim contains the user's tenant.

If the user used a Microsoft Account (MSA), their issuer claims will contain the following GUID for the MSA tenant: `9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad`

The full value of the issuer will be:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0
```

Any other GUID indicates that the user signed in using Azure AD and the GUID value will represent their Azure AD tenant.

For more information check out the id_token section of the [Token Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#types-of-tokens) documentation.