# Azure AD V2 / msal.js restrict personal accounts?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm using msal.js to allow users to sign in with their AAD accounts. I created the application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ using an account in the target tenant. I was under the impression that doing this would create the application under that tenant as well and that msal.js would just work. However, when `loginRedirect()` is called, I end up at the /common/ endpoint, and I'm allowed to sign in using all kinds of organization and personal accounts.

I was able to redirect to the correct login url by specifying the authority like so:

```
new Msal.UserAgentApplication({client_id}, 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/', () => {});
```

However, this still doesn't restrict signing in using only accounts from that organization. In fact, I can also login with personal accounts.

I read from [Is there a way to find whether authentication followed MSA or Azure AD in MSAL.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432124/is-there-a-way-to-find-whether-authentication-followed-msa-or-azure-ad-in-msal-j) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens that I could use the Guid portion of the `iss` property of the decoded `id_token` to determine if the user signed in using MSA or AAD. However, this always returns the same value which is `https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/` regardless if I sign in using MSA or other accounts.

My question is how do I enforce signing in only with user accounts from the same tenant, and if I can't do that, how do I at least get a value to check whether the user signed in using MSA or an account from the same tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `organizations` instead of `common` in the authority to allow only AAD accounts:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations
```

If you wanted only Microsoft accounts, you can use `consumers`.

To allow all, use `common`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints

When you create an app in the new v2 portal, the app will be multi-tenant by default, and you won't find it in your directory.

If you want a single-tenant app, use v1.

Comment: If I use organizations, is there any way to check that the user who signed in came from a specific tenant?

Comment: There should be a `tid` claim in the token which is the tenant id.

Comment: Thank you. I believe tid and iss are returning the correct values - I failed to realize that the MS account I am using to sign in was also added to the directory as a Guest, hence it was receiving the same value as if I signed in using my AAD account.